# HBase - deleteAll with rowPrefix - how to do in Java?

Tags: hbase, hbase-shell

**On Hbase shell -**

```
deleteall 'table', {rowPrefixFilter=> '100_x_'}
```

**How to do it in Java? Is below the right way?**

````
scan.setRowPrefixFilter('100_x_');
scan.addFilter(new KeyOnlyFilter());```

// now go over the result list and build a list of Delete

List<Delete> deletes = new ArrayList();
result.forEach( row -> {
Delete delete = new Delete (row.getRow());
deletes.add(delete).
});

HTable.delete(deletes).
````

Actually, is that what 'deleteAll' command also does internally? Does it also first pull matching all rowsKeys on the client side and then send a delete command? I hope not.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58868697/deleting-all-hbase-rows-with-key-filters), but I guess there needs to be a better way of deleting matching records on the server w/o pulling the matching rowsKey first on the client side.

Comment: Any help is appreciated.